# circle svg with 8 arc rotate clockwise and anti-clockwise

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Please help me on this.

I've this svg shown in this image [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuTDa.jpg)
and its my code here:

```js
var arcpoint = [-31, -66, -101, -136, -171, -206, -241, -276];
colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "orange", "yellow", "purple", "pink"];
for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
  document.querySelector("#" + colors[i]).style.strokeDashoffset = arcpoint[i];
}
```

```css
svg {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

circle {
  stroke-width: 4px;
  fill: transparent;
}

#gray {
  stroke: gray;
}

#red {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-dasharray: 35.5, 284;
  /* length of arc, circumference of circle */
}

#green {
  stroke: green;
  stroke-dasharray: 35.5, 284;
  /* length of arc, circumference of circle */
}

#blue {
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-dasharray: 35.5, 284;
  /* length of arc, circumference of circle */
}

#orange {
  stroke: orange;
  stroke-dasharray: 35.5, 284;
  /* length of arc, circumference of circle */
}

#yellow {
  stroke: yellow;
  stroke-dasharray: 35.5, 284;
  /* length of arc, circumference of circle */
}

#purple {
  stroke: purple;
  stroke-dasharray: 35.5, 284;
  /* length of arc, circumference of circle */
}

#pink {
  stroke: pink;
  stroke-dasharray: 35.5, 284;
  /* length of arc, circumference of circle */
}
```

```html
<div id="orbit">
  <svg viewBox='0 0 100 100'>
     <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='45' id='gray'/>
     <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='45' id='red'/>
     <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='45' id='green'/>
     <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='45' id='blue'/>
     <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='45' id='orange'/>
     <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='45' id='yellow'/>
     <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='45' id='purple'/>
     <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='45' id='pink'/>
   </svg>
</div>
```

Now i want to rotate all arc's clockwise and anti-clockwise by clicking on a button. 
Problem is, my mind is stuck on how to make function and loop to change colors and rotate clockwise and anti-clockwise.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want infinite rotations?

Comment: @MrigankPawagi No i don't want infinite rotation. i want colors sequence to rotate on next point, one by one. for example: if red color arc strockDashoffset value is -31, then clicking on rotate clockwise change its value to -66, and others too by difference of -35.

Comment: So you want it to step around by one colour step each time you click? Is that it?

Comment: yes @PaulLeBeau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this?

```js
var colors = ["gray", "red", "green", "blue", "orange", "yellow", "purple", "pink"];
var rotateOffset = 0;

function setColours()
{
  for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    var arcIndex = (i + rotateOffset) % colors.length;
    document.querySelector("#" + colors[i]).style.strokeDashoffset = (arcIndex ) * -35.3;
  }
}

// Set initial colours
setColours();
    

// Button handlers
document.getElementById('left').addEventListener("click", function() {
  rotateOffset += (colors.length - 1);
  setColours();
});

document.getElementById('right').addEventListener("click", function() {
  rotateOffset++
  setColours();
});
```

```css
svg {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
circle {
  stroke-width: 4px;
  fill: transparent;
}
#gray{
  stroke: gray;
}
#red{
  stroke: red;
  stroke-dasharray: 35.5, 284; /* length of arc, circumference of circle */
}
#green{
  stroke: green;
  stroke-dasharray: 35.5, 284; /* length of arc, circumference of circle */
}
#blue{
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-dasharray: 35.5, 284; /* length of arc, circumference of circle */
}
#orange{
  stroke: orange;
  stroke-dasharray: 35.5, 284; /* length of arc, circumference of circle */
}
#yellow{
  stroke: yellow;
  stroke-dasharray: 35.5, 284; /* length of arc, circumference of circle */
}
#purple{
  stroke: purple;
  stroke-dasharray: 35.5, 284; /* length of arc, circumference of circle */
}
#pink{
  stroke: pink;
  stroke-dasharray: 35.5, 284; /* length of arc, circumference of circle */
}
```

```html
<div id="orbit" >
  <svg viewBox='0 0 100 100' >
    <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='45' id='gray'/>
    <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='45' id='red'/>
    <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='45' id='green'/>
    <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='45' id='blue'/>
    <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='45' id='orange'/>
    <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='45' id='yellow'/>
    <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='45' id='purple'/>
    <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='45' id='pink'/>
  </svg>
</div>

<button id="left">left</button>
<button id="right">right</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use a css animation and then just add the class to your svg on a click function. Like this:

```js
var arcpoint = [-31, -66, -101, -136, -171, -206, -241, -276];
colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "orange", "yellow", "purple", "pink"];
for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        document.querySelector("#" + colors[i]).style.strokeDashoffset = arcpoint[i];
    }
    
    
$('.left').click(function(){
    $("#orbit svg").attr("class", "rotating-left");
});
$('.right').click(function(){
    $("#orbit svg").attr("class", "rotating-right");
});
```

```css
svg {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
circle {
  stroke-width: 4px;
  fill: transparent;
}
#gray{
  stroke: gray;
}
#red{
  stroke: red;
  stroke-dasharray: 35.5, 284; /* length of arc, circumference of circle */
}
#green{
  stroke: green;
  stroke-dasharray: 35.5, 284; /* length of arc, circumference of circle */
}
#blue{
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-dasharray: 35.5, 284; /* length of arc, circumference of circle */
}
#orange{
  stroke: orange;
  stroke-dasharray: 35.5, 284; /* length of arc, circumference of circle */
}
#yellow{
  stroke: yellow;
  stroke-dasharray: 35.5, 284; /* length of arc, circumference of circle */
}
#purple{
  stroke: purple;
  stroke-dasharray: 35.5, 284; /* length of arc, circumference of circle */
}
#pink{
  stroke: pink;
  stroke-dasharray: 35.5, 284; /* length of arc, circumference of circle */
}

.rotating-right {
  
  animation: rotating-right 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes rotating-right {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.rotating-left {
  
  animation: rotating-left 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes rotating-left {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="orbit" >
      <svg viewBox='0 0 100 100' >
          <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='45' id='gray'/>
          <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='45' id='red'/>
          <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='45' id='green'/>
          <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='45' id='blue'/>
          <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='45' id='orange'/>
          <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='45' id='yellow'/>
          <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='45' id='purple'/>
          <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='45' id='pink'/>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <button class="left">left</button>
    <button class="right">right</button>
```

Notice I used `$("#orbit svg").attr("class", "rotating-right");` as you can't use `addClass` on a `svg` with `jQuery`

Comment: Thanks for helping me! But i want it to rotate in on specific point. i want to rotate colors sequence one by one, so then i can get value by color then.